# headers not being sent the user browser for downloading.

Tags: php

i have script for downloading file like pdf, etc....
some time when i click on the link for downloading it work and download the file and some time when i click on the link to download it give error "headers_sent=false". i tried "off" "buffer_output" in php.ini and "on" it but same problem. also tried  "ob_end_clean" before my header setting, but nothing work.
the problem here header not being sent to the user browser, i don't know why.

my php code.

```
<?php
ob_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$company =$_GET['company']; 
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
if($id <= 0)
{
die('The ID is invalid!');
}
else
{
$dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'sqldata', 'sqldata', 'balhaf');
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
}
$query = "SELECT mime, name, size, data FROM $company WHERE id = $id";
$result = $dbLink->query($query);
if($result)
{
if($result->num_rows == 1) {
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if( headers_sent() )
{
die('Headers Sent');
}
else
{
echo "error";
}
var_dump(headers_sent());
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Cache-Control: ");
header("Pragma: ");
header("Content-Type: ". $row['mime']);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". $row['name']);
header("Content-Length: ".$row['size']);
header('Expires: 0');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header("Cache-control: private");
header('Pragma: private');


echo $row['data'];
exit;
}
else {
echo 'Error! No image exists with that ID.';
}
@mysqli_free_result($result);
}
else
{
echo "Error! Query failed: <pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
}
@mysqli_close($dbLink);
}
}
else
{
echo 'Error! No ID was passed.';
}
?>
```

Comment: So what is the content type? You should only be sending a single content type header

Comment: @Mark Baker, see my code you will find the content type. what you mean sending single content type?? give an example please..

Comment: You have multiple Content-Type headers

Comment: @hadi I see __three__ content type headers in your code, you should only be sending __one__

Comment: @ Mark Baker, i have comment  2 content type and used one, but same problem.

Comment: Also check if the program dies before reaching the header() output!

Answer (score 0):

The header() function should be before any output commands. Please try to remove the var_dump and the echo.

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php:

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

**Edit**: Also check if the program dies before reaching the header() outputs! This can happend if you have an invalid id of the mysql connection failed. Generally, it is better to handle such cases with a way other than die (e.g. log an error to a file).

Edit 2: If the browser displays garbage check that `$row['name']` has the correct file path

Comment: like what outoutp command? can you show me in my code please.

Comment: Can you comment out the echo("error") and the var_dump(headers_sent()) and try again? Also what Mark said in his comment bellow your question, you have multiple Content-Type headers but you should have only one.

Comment: @ Vasilis, just i did comment the var_dump and the echo, and used single Content-Type, but same problem.

Comment: Can you also remove the two empty header values: header("Cache-Control: "); and header("Pragma: ");

Comment: i did i removed header("Cache-Control: "); and header("Pragma: ");, same problem it show garbage on the screen when i click download.

Comment: im pretty sure mysql id is valid.

Comment: Which Content-Type header did you leave? If it shows garbage it may mean that your Content-Type header is wrong. For example for a pdf file you need Content-Type:application/pdf

Comment: i used header("Content-Type: application/pdf");, same problem.garbage  on the screen.

Comment: im storing my files in mysql database using BLOB data type.